# Where and how store the selected quantities and show them in the next page?

Tags: php, laravel

I have basketball match details page "single.blade.php" and a page to purchase a ticket "payment.blade.php". In the match details page, the user can select through a select how many tickets want for each type. For example the user can select 2 tickets for the central bench and 2 for the left side bench and then click "Next".

**Doubt:** When the user click "Next", Im in doubt about how to get the quantity of each ticket selected by the user in the match details page and send that information to the payment page when "next" button is clicked to be possible to show in the payment page a summary of the selected ticket types and quantities by the user in the next page (payment page).

**FrontController has the single() method to show the match details page:**

```
public function single($id){
    $match = Match::where('id', $id)->first();
    $tickets = Ticket::where('match_id', $match_id->id)->get();
    return view('matchs.show')->with('match',$match)->with('match', $match)->with('tickets', $tickets);
}
```

**In match details page the types of tickets listed and for each one there is a select menu so the user can select how many tickets want for each one**

```
<ul>
    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <li>
            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 
            <form method="post" action="{{route('matchs.payment', ['id' => $match->id, 'slug' => $match->slug])}}">

                <select name={{ $ticket->title }}>
                    <option selected>0</option>
                    ...
                </select>
            </form>
            <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>0.00€</span>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Payment Page"/>
    </form>
</ul>
```

After user select the quantities and click "Next" he should go to the payment page and the selected types and quatities in the previous page (match details page) should be presented in this payment page to show a summary.

So, I created a PaymentController and I created a storeQuantity() method:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function storeQuantity(Request $request){
        //dd($request->all());
        return view('matchs.payment');
    }
}
```

Route for this:

```
Route::post('/match/{id}/{slug?}/payment', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeQuantity',
    'as'   =>'matchs.payment'
]);
```

The dd($request->all()); shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "center_bench" => "1"
  "left_bench"   => "1"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use array for name of your select element like and place form outside foreach

```
 <ul>
 <form method="post" action="{{route('matchs.payment', ['id' => $match->id,'slug' => $match->slug])}}">
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
    <li>
        <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 


            <select name="ticket[{{ $ticket->title }}]">
                <option selected>0</option>
                ...
            </select>
        <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
    </li>
@endforeach
<li>
    <span>TOTAL</span>
    <span>0.00€</span>
</li>
<input type="submit" value="Go To Payment Page"/>
</form>
</ul>
```

Now you can access ticket as array and using foreach you can access each value.
For checking use `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Thanks, but now where to store that array so that is possible to show the info inside the array in the next page (payment page)?

Comment: send the array as parameters check this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: So you are saying that in the PaymentController in the storeQuantity method to get the array "ticket" and return that array to the payment page?

Comment: Yes, If you want to display it in your payment page

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options, 1 is what afsal c said.

Another one is to use sessions if you want the selected options to persist.

As the documentation says you can save something in session with `Session::put("key", $value)` and retreive with `Session::get("key")`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session